# to_specs': Could not find 'thor' (~> 0.17.0) - did find: [thor-0.18.1] (Gem::LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, padrino

I am getting error in padrino to_specs': Could not find 'thor' (~> 0.17.0) - did find: [thor-0.18.1] (Gem::LoadError) . I could not find what to do. I have installed even thor-0.15.0, thor-0.17.0 also , But it was not working. same error I was getting. Can any body suggest me, How best way to start padrino. It was working previously. But I don't know why now I am not able to start padrino.

> Following Error I am getting 
>   while I am doing : padrino start 
>   /usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in `to_specs': Could not find 'thor' (~> 0.17.0) - did find: [thor-0.18.1,thor-0.15.4] (Gem::LoadError) <br/>
>     from /usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:1268:in`block in activate_dependencies' 
>     from /usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:1257:in `each' <br/>
>     from /usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:1257:in`activate_dependencies' 
>     from /usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:1239:in `activate' <br/>
>     from /usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:48:in`gem' 
>     from /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/padrino:22:in `'

Comment: Please add your code causing this error to the question.